# Django Python - Displaying data to user in user-friendly manner from models.py to HTML template through views.py

Tags: python, django

I am using Django as a webframework for a project. I am having trouble displaying data that was saved into models.py to my html page. I was able to get something displayed by querying the db with the objects.all() function, but it is not displayed in a user-friendly manner. I am not sure how to format it. For a little background we are doing sentiment analysis with Python's textblob package. The analysis is performed in analysis.py and is called in our views.py by using the call_command(analysis) that Django provides.

Below is what we have:

analysis.py

```
    pt_terrible = SentimentPercentage(pt_terrible = (len(terrible_list)/len(activity_text_list)))
    pt_terrible.save()
    pt_bad = SentimentPercentage(pt_bad = (len(bad_list)/len(activity_text_list)))
    pt_bad.save()
    pt_neutral = SentimentPercentage(pt_neutral = (len(neutral_list)/len(activity_text_list)))
    pt_neutral.save()
    pt_good = SentimentPercentage(pt_good = (len(good_list)/len(activity_text_list)))
    pt_good.save()
    pt_excellent = SentimentPercentage(pt_excellent = (len(excellent_list)/len(activity_text_list)))
    pt_excellent.save()
```

models.py

```
class SentimentPercentage(models.Model):
    pt_terrible = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    pt_bad = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    pt_neutral = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    pt_good = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    pt_excellent = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%f' % (self.pt_terrible)
```

At this point I am only trying to return the data stored in pt_terrible... however, I would like to return each value stored in these attributes eventually.

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.management import call_command
from sawa.models import Sentiment, SentimentPercentage

def results(request):
    sentiment = call_command('analysis')
    pt_sentiment = SentimentPercentage.objects.all()

    context = {'pt_sentiment': pt_sentiment, 'sentiment': sentiment}
    return render(request, 'sawa/results.html', context)
```

results.html

```
           <form>
                <fieldset>

                    <!-- RESULTS WILL BE POSTED HERE -->

                    <div>{{pt_sentiment}}</div>


                    <p>RESULTS WILL BE POSTED HERE</p>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Here are the results I keeping getting in a link:

How do I get these results to display in a more user-friendly manner? Something along the lines of:

Percent of Terrible Reviews: 0.30%
Percent of Bad Reviews: 4% .... etc.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions, I have a feeling it has something to do with the how I am querying the data, then how I am formatting it within results.html.

I have a better formatted result! But now I need to remove all of the duplicates from the list and remove items without values.. below is part of the result I am receiving in an image:

EDIT TO QUESTION

[Result with for loop in results.html template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoTgs.png)

[Result without for loop and just variable reference in results.html template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKh09.png)

Answer (score 1):

The display you have is as if you are printing list of `SentimentPercentage` objects, which is expected.

To get rid of the square brackets `[]`, you need to know that it represents python list notation, so looping through the list would be the first step:

```
{% for item in pt_sentiment %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Secondly, `<SentimentPercentage: 0.003021>` is the `__unicode__` representation of your `SentimentPercentage` model objects. If you need to print a percentage of your `pt_terrible`  or `pt_bad`, you need to have methods in your model to show them. A good practice would be python [property methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class SentimentPercentage(models.Model)
    # your fields
    @property
    def show_pt_bad(self):
        return '%f' % self.pt_bad
```

Then you would do:

```
{% for item in pt_sentiment %}
    Percent of Bad Reviews: {{ item.show_pt_bad }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit:**

To remove duplicates you do:

```
pt_sentiment = SentimentPercentage.objects.all().distinct()
```

You should've read [how to make queries in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/).

Comment: Excellent! It is starting to get closer to what I want it to look like. The loop worked and now it is printing every item in the loop in a more user-friendly manner and an associated value if applicable... However, how do I remove duplicates in the list? and not show any blank items. Above I edited my original question to include a new image of my result.

Comment: Is there another query I can use besides objects.all() that Django provides?

Comment: Edited my answer. It's obviously true that django can do a lot besides `all()` query. Check out the doc.

Comment: I'm still having trouble just displaying the values i want. It seems to save all of these objects into a list. For some reason, some of these values are "None" while the others are the numbers I need for each attribute. When using the distinct method, I'm able to remove the duplicates and get it down to "Percent of Terrible Reviews: None" , "Percent of Terrible Reviews: 0.30..." I've tried a few things to get rid of "None" values without much luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's related to the process that you create those objects. You keep creating `SentimentPercentage` with only one field filled, like `SentimentPercentage(pt_terrible = (len(terrible_list)/len(activity_text_list)))`, then if you want to display the field value `pt_bad` on that objects, obviously it's `None`, right?

Comment: Okay, I tried changing the way I create those objects in analysis.py  `pt_object = SentimentPercentage(pt_terrible = (len(terrible_list)/len(activity_text_list)), pt_bad = (len(bad_list)/len(activity_text_list)), pt_neutral = (len(neutral_list)/len(activity_text_list)), pt_good = (len(good_list)/len(activity_text_list)), pt_excellent = (len(excellent_list)/len(activity_text_list)))
        
        pt_object.save()`   my result changes if I leave the for loop, but it does something similar by showing repeated results. If I remove the loop, the results do not appear. I will edit my post.

Comment: By the way, thank you for helping me out with this! I am new to coding and this is teaching me a lot.